# This IQ Test Is Broken!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I recently attempted an online IQ test out of curiosity, but for some reason it didn't tell me my final score... (or maybe my IQ is so low I can't find it...)

It was a typical IQ test with all the usual gimmicks, a crappy number sequence, weird missing shapes etc (and although it started easy, it did get harder), but I reached the end and it simply said 'Your IQ is: ...' but failed to load a score.

Maybe, if you can fix this broken IQ test, it'll tell you *your* IQ instead!

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

$$\huge\text{What is your IQ?}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on @ParclyTaxel's answer

> LIMiTLESS

because

> @ParclyTaxel describes how to find the letter for each puzzle. Each puzzle also indicates how to lay the letters out in a 3x3 grid by the squares that are missing. In the case of the first puzzle, laying the numbers in a 3x3 grid left to right and top to bottom puts M and S in the top and bottom right. In the second puzzle there is a full grid square in the middle right. All other puzzles are themselves 3x3 grids. The lines in puzzle 6 needed to complete the two uppercase Is form a lowercase i.

---

Solutions to puzzle:

> 1. 13, 19 = M, S
> 2. 6 - 6th square is complete and gives 'L'
> 3. 'Eye' = 9 = 'I'
> 4. 5, 19 = E, S
> 5. [image] = L, T
> 6. [image] = 'i'
>
> Final answer:
>
>  [image]

Comment: Yep! That was the trick I was looking for! Good job, I'll add a couple of diagrams to explain a couple of the puzzles too, hoping thats ok

Answer (score 6):

Solutions to mini-puzzles:

> 1. 13, 19 (M, S)
>  2. 5* (E)
>  3. Set  (wave) = 5,  (eyes) = 18,  (clap) = 10 to get that ?? =  (eye, 9; I)
>  4. Semimagic square with constant 30; 5, 19 (E, S)
>  5. Each row and column satisfies A XNOR B = C; 100/100/111 (L) and 111/010/010 (T)
>  6. Shift top (bottom) parts of middle squares right (left) cyclically to get whole letters (I, L) (@fljx)
>  Any numbers are transformed through A1Z26.

From @justforplaylists:

> Each puzzle may be laid out in a 3×3 grid, with missing values indicating where the respective values should be placed. This gives **LIMITLESS**.

> I have a qualm with mini-puzzle 2, since there are really six squares in the picture (the tiny one formed by the intersection of two squares included).

Comment: Afraid you're quite far away from the answer here. Obviously most of the mini-puzzles here are correct but you're missing the key idea and answer

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yes. Where is the other information?

Comment: not giving it up that easy! This should be straightforward enough for someone to solve without any hints needed. If it goes 24hours then I’ll follow standard procedure and release a hint

Comment: For (6): ROT13(Fuvsg gur zvqqyr ebj evtug bar pryy, naq gur obggbz ebj yrsg bar pryy, gb trg YVZOVP. Fb gur zvqqyr pryy pbagnvaf gur obggbz bs bar V naq gur gbc bs nabgure, abg n fvatyr yvar.) Not sure if that helps much though.

Comment: @fljx ROT13(Vg pbhyq or vagrecergrq nf gjb unys V'f, znxvat n jubyr V)

Comment: Puzzle 2 should give 6, which indicates tile 6, which is complete and contains an 'L', puzzle 6 merely gives 'i'